# Remove (sub)plot, but keep axis label in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a subplot plot in matplotlib with, say, 2 rows and 2 columns, but I only have 3 things to plot and want to keep the **lower left** subplot empty. However, I still want there to be a y-axis label at that position, which is supposed to refer to the whole second row.

This is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1]
y = [2, 3]

ax = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0))
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_ylabel('first row')

ax = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 1))
ax.plot(x, y)

ax = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (1, 0))
ax.set_ylabel('second row')
# ax.axis('off')     <---- This would remove the label, too

ax = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (1, 1))
ax.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

I have tried using `axis('off')`, but that removes the label, too. (Same, if I move it one line up, i.e. above `ax.set_ylabel('second row')`.

So the result so far looks like this:

[image: lower left plot y u no go away]

I want the empty white box (not just its black bounding box or ticks and tick labels) to disappear. Is this possible and if yes, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you will need to remove the elements of the axis individually in order to keep the ylabel, because the ylabel is itself also an element of the axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
fig.set_facecolor("#ecfaff")
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    if i!=2:
        ax.plot([3,4,6])
    if not i%2:
        ax.set_ylabel("My label")

# make xaxis invisibel
axes[1,0].xaxis.set_visible(False)
# make spines (the box) invisible
plt.setp(axes[1,0].spines.values(), visible=False)
# remove ticks and labels for the left axis
axes[1,0].tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False)
#remove background patch (only needed for non-white background)
axes[1,0].patch.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Tailored to my initial example, using `ax` wherever this solution uses `axes[1,0]`. Additionally, I had to adjust one more thing in order to also remove the right y-axis ticks in the lower left plot: `ax.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False, right=False)`

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way:

```
plt.gca().set_yticklabels([])
plt.gca().set_xticklabels([])
plt.gca().set_xticks([])
plt.gca().set_yticks([])
```

Comment: this doesn't remove the spines (box)