# How to add labels to the axes of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting 8 subplots into a figure as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(8)
label = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
data = [0.6, 0.4, 1.3, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.6, 0.2]
plt.xlim(0,2)
for i in range(8):
    axs[i].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    axs[i].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    axs[i].set_xlim([0, 2])
    axs[i].axvline(data[i],linestyle='--')
    axs[i].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
axs[7].get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
plt.show()
```

This looks like:

[image]

In order to label the subplots I would like to write `label[i]` (see code above) to the left of subplot `i`. How can you do that?

Comment: Hi, do you want to add a label to the x or y axis? Also, you can add a title for each ``axs[i]``. Which one do you want?

Comment: @DanielLima For the first subplot I would just like "A" written to its left (by the y-axis), for example. I don't there will be room to have the titles in the subplots themselves.

Comment: `axs[i].set_ylabel(label[i])`?

Comment: @bnaecker How would I then get rid of the numerical y axis label as I would have to do axs[i].get_yaxis().set_visible(True) ?

Comment: Take a look at this, may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155654/remove-subplot-but-keep-axis-label-in-matplotlib

Comment: Something like `axs[i].text(-0.1,0.2,label[i])`?

Comment: @BigBen that actually works! Do you want to post an answer or shall I delete the question?

Comment: The proper approach would be to not set the y axis off and remove the ticks. I'll post an answer with this.

Comment: @Anush You don't, just set the ticks to nothing: `axs[i].set_yticks(())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As a quick fix), you might just be able to use [`Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html), for example:

```
axs[i].text(-0.1,0.2,label[i])
```

Adjust the `x` and `y` arguments as needed depending on the length of the labels.

[image]

As mentioned in the comments, another (*much better*) option is to keep the y-axis visible, but then set the ticks to nothing:

```
axs[i].set_yticks(())
axs[i].set_ylabel(label[i], rotation=0, ha='right', va='center')
```

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, the proper approach would be to not set the y axis off, and remove the ticks.

The trick is to remove the two lines with `axs[i].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)` and add the following two lines:

```
axs[i].tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False)
axs[i].set_ylabel(label[i])
```

Please, consider the following code as a full answer (edited to include bnaecker's suggestion):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close('all')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(8, sharex="col")
label = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
data = [0.6, 0.4, 1.3, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.6, 0.2]
plt.xlim(0, 2)
for i in range(8):
    axs[i].set_xlim([0, 2])
    axs[i].tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False)
    axs[i].axvline(data[i], linestyle='--')
    axs[i].set_ylabel(label[i])
plt.show()
```

The figure should look like this:

[image: img]

Comment: This is a nice answer, but the business of setting the x-axis invisible isn't needed. We can directly share the x-axis between all subplots with `fig, axs = plt.subplots(8, sharex="col")`. Then the `set_visible` call on each axis isn't necessary.